# Cannot get quotes right

Tags: javascript, quotes

I am having a hard time getting the quotes right in this code. Don't work so I am guessing the quotes are wrong.

```
html+='<img src="' + noteDirectory + '"/ "' + currentNote + '".png>'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
html+='<img src="' + noteDirectory + '/' + currentNote + '.png">';
```

A better way to look at it would be: You just need `"` after `src=` and between `.png` and the last `>`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
html += '<img src="' + noteDirectory + '/' + currentNote + '.png">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html+='<img src="' + noteDirectory + '/' + currentNote + '.png">';
```